# How to save nltk Text.similar() with variable

Tags: python, nltk

I'm a noob in nltk and python.Recently I got a problem,I want to save what text.similar() show in terminal in a variable,but I failed many times.How could I save it?

```
text = nltk.Text(word.lower() for word in nltk.corpus.brown.words())
save = []
for word in nltk.word_tokenize("i want to slove this problem"):
    save.append(text.similar(word))
```

Sadly,I found there is nothing in save[].Then I test code "word = text.similar('women')",I also found there is nothing in "word". I realized it seams I couldn't save text.similar().
What should I do to save it?

Answer (score 8):

Instances of `nltk.Text` are really meant only for interactive exploration.  It dumps a lot of stuff to the console, but really doesn't return any constructed objects from it's functions.

What you want in this case is the `nltk.ContextIndex` class.  Using this class...

```py
import nltk
import nltk.text
import nltk.corpus

idx = nltk.text.ContextIndex([word.lower( ) for word in nltk.corpus.brown.words( )])
save = [ ]
for word in nltk.word_tokenize("i want to solve this problem"):
    save.append(idx.similar_words(word))
```

When done, `save` will be a nest list of the most frequent words in the contexts of "i", "want", "to", etc.

Take a look at the [online nltk.text.Text documentation](http://nltk.github.com/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.Text), specifically the `similar` method, where it references `nltk.text.ContextIndex`

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer provided by @parselmouth but I thought I'd show you another way to do it as well. This is done by redirecting `stdout` . You can then used the stored value `storable_output` for other operations afterwards.

**Code**

```
import sys
import io

orig_stdout = sys.stdout

out = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = out

text1.similar("monstrous")

storable_output = out.getvalue()

sys.stdout = orig_stdout

print(storable_output)
```

**Output**

```
true contemptible christian abundant few part mean careful puzzled
mystifying passing curious loving wise doleful gamesome singular
delightfully perilous fearless
```

Note: `text1` is imported using `from nltk.book import *`