# Override a function in nltk - Error in ContextIndex class

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, similarity

I am using [`text.similar('example')`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.text.Text.similar) function from [`nltk.Text`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html) module.

(Which ***prints*** the similar words for a given word based on corpus.)

However I want to store that list of words in a list. But the function itself returns `None`.

```
#text is a variable of nltk.Text module
simList = text.similar("physics")
>>> a = text.similar("physics")
the and a in science this which it that energy his of but chemistry is
space mathematics theory as mechanics
>>> a
>>> a
# a contains no value.
```

So should I modify the source function itself? But I don't think it is a good practice. So how can I override that function so that it returns the value?

Edit - Referring [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537720/how-to-save-nltk-text-similar-with-variable), I tried using the `ContextIndex` class. But I am getting the following error.

```
  File "test.py", line 39, in <module>
    text = nltk.text.ContextIndex(word.lower() for word in words)   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/nlpenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/text.py", line 56, in __init__
    for i, w in enumerate(tokens))   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/nlpenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 1752, in __init__
    for (cond, sample) in cond_samples:   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/nlpenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/text.py", line 56, in <genexpr>
    for i, w in enumerate(tokens))   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/nlpenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/text.py", line 43, in _default_context
    right = (tokens[i+1].lower() if i != len(tokens) - 1 else '*END*') TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

This is my line 39 of test.py

```
text = nltk.text.ContextIndex(word.lower() for word in words)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save nltk Text.similar() with variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537720/how-to-save-nltk-text-similar-with-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because the `ContextIndex` constructor is trying to take the `len()` of your token list (the argument `tokens`). But you actually pass it as a generator, hence the error. To avoid the problem, just pass a true list, e.g.:

```
text = nltk.text.ContextIndex(list(word.lower() for word in words))
```