# store return of NLTK's .similar()

Tags: nlp, nltk

Is there a way for me to store what the .similar() function in the NLTK library returns? Right now, if I have the line text.similar('woman') in my code, it prints it to the output and I can't store those similar words in a data structure such as a list or to a file. I'd like to be able to do that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for drawing my attention to this question. I have posted my answer on the same question asked by another user previously i.e. [How to save nltk Text.similar() with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537720/how-to-save-nltk-text-similar-with-variable) . Please take a look at that question, it looks like there are posted solutions for this problem.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I tried that but it doesn't seem to be working, it returns an empty list regardless of what string I put in.

Comment: Have you tried both solutions? I have tested my solution and it gives you a string which can then be transformed to a list.